# Curious "compile" function in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

The full code is in [here of plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWZTUi?p=info)

When I remove the **compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude)** function, the functionality is ok

```
app.directive('whatIsInThese', ['$compile', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
 compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
       // this compile function is very curious and hard to explain
       // i have do nothing here
    },
 link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
     scope.getTestUrl = function() {
        return "test.html";
     };
    var these = attrs.whatIsInThese.split(' ');
    var html = '<div ng-include src="getTestUrl()"></div>';
    var el = angular.element(html);
    var compiled = $compile(el);
    elem.append(el);
    compiled(scope);
}
};
}]);
```

can anyone explain it why this happen?

Comment: The compile function is supposed to return the linking function. As the angular documentation states, when the compile property is defined, the link property is not used.

Comment: can you explain more about "why compile property is defined, link property is not used", thanks

Comment: That's just the way angular designed it. It didn't have to behave this way, but it is what it is;

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation of [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)

> The compile function deals with transforming the template DOM.[...] The
>   link property is used only if the compile property is not defined.

So this:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.getTestUrl = function () {
        return "test.html";
    };
    var these = attrs.whatIsInThese.split(' ');
    var html = '<div ng-include src="getTestUrl()"></div>';
    var el = angular.element(html);
    var compiled = $compile(el);
    elem.append(el);
    compiled(scope);
}
```

is the same as

```
compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.getTestUrl = function () {
            return "test.html";
        };
        var these = attrs.whatIsInThese.split(' ');
        var html = '<div ng-include src="getTestUrl()"></div>';
        var el = angular.element(html);
        var compiled = $compile(el);
        elem.append(el);
        compiled(scope);
    }
};
```